# Sublime Text LatexTools fail

Tags: latexmk, sublime-text, perl

I am using Sublime Text 2 with LatexTools on OS X 10.6. When I build, I get "TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... done."
Yet Skim does not open the PDF. The problem might be related to the result of typing 'latexmk' in Terminal:

`File::Path version 2.08 required--this is only version 2.07_02 at /usr/texbin/latexmk line 121.`

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to update your Perl installation, since it appears to be several years outdated.  (The release date of version 2.08 of the `File::Path` module is  2009-10-04; this is the minimum version that `latexmk` tests for.)

However, you could try changing the `latexmk.pl` file to change the line

```
use File::Path 2.08 qw( make_path );
```

to

```
use File::Path 2.07 qw( make_path );
```

If that gives you no trouble, you are OK.

(Perhaps some experts on `Perl` and its history could suggest whether the version test that I wrote into the `latexmk` code is too conservative.)